# Не могу разобраться с выводом в двумерном массиве

Tags: php, sql

`print_r` выборки возвращает массив

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => username1 [0] => username1 ) [1] => Array ( [username] => username2 [0] => username2 ) )`

Как мне отсюда выбрать только **username1** и **username2**?

сам запрос:

```
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users');
  $sth->execute(array($chat));
  $players_data = $sth->fetchAll();
  

print_r($players_data);
```

Пишу такой цикл, но выводится по два раза **username1** и **username2** в `<select>`
**php:**

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($players_data); $i++){
foreach ($players_data[$i] as $key => $value) {

  $players.='<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'.'<br>';

}
}
```

Comment: `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` вот тут почитайте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в отправке запроса.

Потребовалось лишь заменить строку

`$players_data = $sth->fetchAll();`
**на**
`$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: А еще есть `fetchAll` c аргументом `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`

Answer (score 0):

Просто увлеклись в циклами, достаточно вот этого

```
foreach ($players_data as $player) {
    $players .= '<option value="' . $player['username'] . '">' . $player['username'] . '</option>' . '<br>';
}
```